# General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I am trying to execute `grails help` or `grails create-controller Book` in grails project using command prompt.

Error shown in cmd:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\grails start\grails-crud\build.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'D:\grails start\grails-crud\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60
```

Comment: What version of Grails are you using? What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Grails Version: 4.0.10
 JVM Version: 16.0.1

Comment: what Gradle version? I think this may have to do with compatibility of the Gradle version with Java 16. Only Gradle 7.x+ is compatible with Java 16